# Attempting to change Keyboard Backlight levels changes theme

Tags: 12.04, asus, backlight

I'm using an Asus G74SX on Ubuntu 12.04. When I try to change my Keyboard Backlight levels my theme seems to change or crash to a backup.

P.S. My Screen Brightness won't change if I use the keys or even going into display settings manually.

P.S.S I'll be able to post a screen shot when my reputation gets up to 10

It changes to this:

[image]

From This ( note: the normal theme is the window surrounding the picture ):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there might be a key binding configured to change the theme when you press whatever button toggles/changes the keyboard backlight levels.

Does the keyboard backlight level change as well or is it just the theme that changes when you press that key, because if it's just the theme, then it's possible you have to hold down a 'function' key to trigger the keyboard backlight instead of the theme change.

If the keyboard backlight level changes as well as the theme, then I would try changing the keyboard bindings, see if there is one associated with theme changes and disable or change it.

Comment: I'm already using the Fn Key to specify that it should be changing backlight. I also looked through the keyboard shortcuts and there don't appear to be any that should change my theme. The reason I think it's a bug is that the theme it changes to looks like a backup theme for if something crashes.